# Loop through id with javascript quiz form

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

hi I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to make loop with ids 
so every time i push the button it update to the next form id
 i've 9 forms

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>

    <title>
        Quiz project
    </title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jq/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <header>

            <div id="lfup" class="pull-left">Quiz Project</div>

            <div id="riup" class="pull-reight">Horizon</div>

        </header>

        <main>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q1" data-qusetion="1">

                <h3 class="">What is the right way to declare (X) as a local variable in Jquery ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" /><span>&#36;("x = 5");</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" /><span>x = 5 ;</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" /><span>&#36;x = 5 ;</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" /><span>var x = 5 ;</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q2" data-qusetion="2">

                <h3>The Bootstrap grid system is based on how many columns ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" /><span>10</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" /><span>3</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" /><span>6</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" /><span>12</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q3" data-qusetion="3">

                <h3>Which class is used to create a black navigation bar ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" /><span>navbar-inverse</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" /><span>navbar-default</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" /><span>navbar-dark</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" /><span>.navbar-inverse</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q4" data-qusetion="4">

                <h3>What does HTML stand for ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" /><span>Home page Tab Markup Language</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" /><span>Hyperlinks Text Markup Language</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" /><span>Hyper Text Markup Language</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" /><span>Hyperlink Table Must Language</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q5" data-qusetion="5">

                <h3>How do you display a border like this:
                    <br />
                    The top border = 10 pixels<br />
                    The bottom border = 5 pixels<br />
                    The left border = 20 pixels<br />
                    The right border = 1pixel ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" /><span>border-width:10px 5px 20px 1px;</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" /><span>border-width:10px 20px 5px 1px;</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" /><span>border-width:10px 1px 5px 20px;</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" /><span>border-width:1px 5px 20px 10px;</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q6" data-qusetion="6">

                <h3>What is the default value of the position property ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="a" /><span>fixed</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="b" /><span>static</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="c" /><span>relative</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="d" /><span>absolute</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q7" data-qusetion="7">

                <h3>Look at the following selector: $("p"). What does it select in jQuery ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="a" /><span>All p elements</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="b" /><span>The first p element</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="c" /><span>Does nothing</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="d" /><span>It's not even jQuery...</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form class="form-group quesForm" id="q8" data-qusetion="8">

                <h3>To use jQuery, you do not have to do anything. Most browsers (Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and Opera) have the jQuery library built in the browser ?</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q8" value="a" /><span>True</span></li></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 listi"><li><input type="radio" name="q8" value="b" /><span>False</span></li></div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button id="Continue" class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div id="result">

            </div>

            <br />
        </main>
        <footer>

            <div class="pull-left">Web Developer Quiz</div>
            <div class="pull-reight"><a href="http://horizonedu.tk/">&copy; Horizon.tk</a></div>

        </footer>
    </div>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
$(".quesForm").hide();
$("#q1").show();

var arr = ["q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6","q7","q8","q9"];
$.each( arr, function( i, val ){return ( val !== "q9" );});

$(".btn").click(function(){
   $(".quesForm").hide();
   $("#" + val).fadeIn(1500);
   return false;
    });
```

this is the html document what i don't want to repeat this code over and over

```
$("#q1 #Continue").click(function(){
$(".quesForm").hide(); proc("q1");
$("#q2").fadeIn(1500);
return false;
    });
$("#q2 #Continue").click(function(){
$(".quesForm").hide(); proc("q2");
$("#q3").fadeIn(1500);
return false;
    });
```

thank you

Comment: whats problem and put html code too

Comment: Your `$.each` loop is useless, i.e. effectively, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all your script code and Try This

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quesForm").hide();
    $("#q1").show(); 
    var nextFormToShow=1;
    $(".btn").click(function(i){  
       $(".quesForm").hide(); 
       if(nextFormToShow<9)
       {
           $("#q"+(nextFormToShow+1)).fadeIn(1000); 
           nextFormToShow=(nextFormToShow+1);
       }
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you my friend @LoopCoder but I've made some Modification '$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quesForm").hide();
    $("#q1").show();
    
    var nxtForm = 1;
    $(".btn").click(function (i) {
        $(".quesForm").hide(); proc("q"+(nxtForm));
        if(nxtForm<9) {
            $("#q"+(nxtForm+1)).fadeIn(1000);
            nxtForm=(nxtForm+1);
        } else {
            $("#result").fadeIn(1500);
        }
        
        return false ;
    });
});    ' to show result

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding